# SwiftUI ScrollView inside List disappears when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, listview, scrollview, swiftui

If I put multiple horizontal `ScrollView`s inside a `List` they disappear when scrolling. Here is an example:

[image: screenrecording]

Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { _ in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack {
                        Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using iOS 13.3. Adding frames to the `ScrollView` or `HStack` did not help, unfortunately. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: I recommend to use vertical `ScrollView` instead of `List` - no this issue (and other known List-based issue)

Comment: @Asperi A `List` is much better for performance if it has many items. Furthermore, I cannot style a `ScrollView` like a `List` (`GroupedListStyle()`). So just using a `ScrollView` is not a real solution for me.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this?

Comment: @ryansle no, I did not find a fix yet.

Comment: @ThomasVos it was this link that ended up fixing the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810913/content-in-scrollview-as-a-list-item-disappears-when-scrolling-swiftui-why

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug related to items reuse. You can try to fix setting the id in Lists and ScrollViews.

```
List(array, id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(item)")
}.id(UUID().uuidString)
```

More about this fix in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810913/content-in-scrollview-as-a-list-item-disappears-when-scrolling-swiftui-why) and [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/).

Comment: In my case just setting id to the scroll view worked perfectly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! @KarenKarapetyan